# NSIS MUI language popup not appearing

Tags: nsis

I am using NSIS to create an installer for my application. NSIS Mondern UI, to be specific.

This installer is multi-lingual and I am using

```
!insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE
```

etc to ask the language input to the user. On one of the machines, I am not getting the "Select Language" popup. But if I use the normal NSIS commands (not MUI) like `LoadLanguageFile`, `LicenseLangString` etc., it works perfectly fine.

What could be the reason for this behavior? Is it related to any other system/Windows level setting??

Other MUI commands/instructions work perfectly on this machine. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: A little more details please. You only get this behaviour on one machine? What OS is that machine running?

Comment: It really helps if you specify which NSIS you are using when it comes to language issues, ansi or unicode?

Comment: @Bobby: Yes, I see this only on one machine which runs XP SP3  @Anders: I am using NSIS v2.45. How to check if ansi or unicode? (Pardon me for such a stupid question :-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that could be going on here:

- If you use the MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_* defines, NSIS will try to remember the language and not ask again (MUI_LANGDLL_ALWAYSSHOW turns this off)
- If NSIS decides that this machine is only able to display one language (code page issues etc) it will not show the dialog, you can override this with MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try with MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES. Will post my findings soon.

Comment: Issue resolved with setting MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES. Thanks for your inputs.